Cardinality $T_2$ hereditarily Lindelöf spaces
I was wondering if being $T_2$ and hereditarily Lindelöf conditions the cardinality of the space. I noticed that in $\pi$-Base there aren't examples of spaces that are $T_2$ and hereditarily Lindelöf, but have cardinality greater than the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. I know that $T_2$ hereditarily Lindelöf spaces have countable pseudocharacter and countable spread (every discrete subspace has countable cardinality), but I don't know if this would be enough to prove so. Do $T_2$ and hereditarily Lindelöf spaces have cardinality $\leq$ the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$? Or, does anyone know a counterexample?

Edit for the reader: in the Handbook of Set Theoretic Topology it is also proven that $T_1$ spaces with countable pseudocharacter and countable spread have cardinality $\leq$ the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.

Every Hausdorff hereditarily Lindelöf space has size at most continuum, this follows from the following fact (recall that $hL(X)$ is the hereditary Lindelöf degree of $X$)

Theorem (de Groot): For every Hausdorff space $X$, $|X|\le 2^{hL(X)}$

For a proof, see 4.10 in Hodel's chapter in the Handbook of Set Theoretic Topology (page 21).

Thank you so much, Reveillark.
